# How to find this limit when $m,n\rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How to evaluate the following limit:

$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} 2^{n-m} \sum_{i=m}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2}$, where $n>m$?

I believe the limit is zero since we are having the tail of a convergent series here. But the presence of the factor $2^{n-m}$ seems to be an issue, although we can settle it by finding the limit for each $k=n-m$. But is it correct?

Can we have a direct rigorous proof?

Comment: Your title and question don't match. There is no limit as $n\to\infty$ in the question as stated.

Comment: It really depends if $k = n-m$ is fixed or not.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The given condition is $n>m$, so if $m \rightarrow \infty$, clearly $n \rightarrow \infty$. Hence the title. Can you give a proof that the limit does not exist?

Comment: @RRL Here $k=m-n$ is not fixed as m, n both tend to infinity. What do you say in this case?

Comment: We could have both $m$ and $n$ tend t0 infinity yet $k = n - m$ be fixed. For example, $n = m+4$.

Comment: Yes we can have but we need a proof for the general case, where $n-m$ need not be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In the same spirit as RRL answer, we can even find good bounds since
$$S_m=\sum_{i=m}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2}=\psi ^{(1)}(m)$$ and using asymptotics
$$\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{2 m^2}+\frac{1}{6 m^3}-\frac{1}{30
   m^5}<S_m <\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{2 m^2}+\frac{1}{6 m^3}$$

Comment: This is the best answer. Once $k(m)$ is specified we can determine the limit by squeezing. For example if $k(m) = m$ then the limit is $+\infty$ — going back to my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Note that with $k = n-m$ fixed,

$$0 < 2^{n-m}\sum_{i=m}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2} < 2^{k}\sum_{i=m}^\infty \frac{1}{i(i-1)} = \frac{2^k}{m-1}$$

Comment: Please note that here $k=m-n$ is not fixed as both m, n tend to infinity.

Comment: See my first comment and Claude’s answer. I merely show here that the limit must be $0$ “rigorously” as you requested if $k$ is fixed.

Comment: What if k is not fixed?

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\sum_{i=m}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2}-\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{i^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6-\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{i^2} \to 0$$

and by $n=m+k$

$$2^{n-m} \sum_{i=m}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2}=2^{k} \sum_{i=m}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2}\to2^k \cdot 0=0$$

Comment: For each fixed k, the limit is 0, correct. But here m, n both tend to infinity. Can we still say that the limit is 0?

Comment: It depends how $n\to \infty$ with respect to $m$.